# what is the proper command to format the names of big mathematical theories like ZFC/PA etc

Tags: sans-serif, mathematics

The answer to this question is gonna to be very short:

what is the proper command to format the names of big mathematical theories like **ZFC/PA/RCA** etc. I.e. set theory and Peano arithmetic.

I believe that they might be something like sanserif, but I'm not sure.

Can someone help to me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no standard. I've seen several different notations:

- no special formatting;
- italic;
- boldface;
- sans serif medium;
- sans serif boldface.

Possibly others. Do yourself a favor by defining

```
\newcommand{\mt}[1]{\textup{#1}}% no special formatting, ensure upright
%\newcommand{\mt}[1]{\textit{#1}}% italic
%\newcommand{\mt}[1]{\textbf{#1}}% boldface
%\newcommand{\mt}[1]{\textsf{#1}}% sans serif medium
%\newcommand{\mt}[1]{\textsf{\textbf{#1}}}% sans serif boldface
```

and use `\mt{ZFC}` or `\mt{PA}` and so on.

When you decide what formatting suits you best, uncomment the corresponding line or maybe add a new one.

Comment: \textsf is by far what I have encountered the most

Comment: @John I checked Moore “Zermelo's Axiom of Choice” (boldface); Mendelsohn “Introduction to Mathematical Logic” (normal font); Bell-Machover “A Course in Mathematical Logic” (boldface). Maybe sans serif is more fashionable nowadays?